# htaccess rewrite working differently

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, shared-hosting

This is my .htaccess contents on my local development box. It works fine. But when I try the same on my hostgator shared server it does not work.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ perform.php?_api=$1 [QSA]
```

When I replace the last line with

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/japi/perform.php?_api=$1 [L,QSA]
```

It partially works but I loose "POST" parameters sent with the request.

Anybody could shed some light on this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Take away the "L", maybe? Only [QSA] is needed to grab the parameters.

Comment: I tried that. Didn't help. Still lost the other parameters.

Comment: Is there only one parameter?

Comment: Well, the parameter count would change depending on the API. But I am appending only one parameter to the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured what the problem was. Although this was not an issue on the development box nor my bluehost account.

The above mention htaccess code is at a sub directory "japi" and its parent directory contains the wordpress installation. The htaccess of wordpress was causing a issue.

The

```
RewriteBase /
```

needed to be set in the sub folder as well

```
RewriteBase /japi
```

not sure why this worked on my development box or the bluehost box. Maybe the htaccess rules were not being inherited.